# Unable to add class correctly to the table td

Tags: jquery

I want to add redclass or greenclass dynamically depeneding on the values being processed .

Could you please why i am getting greenclass instead of redclass for the last td

Last td belongs to Day 30

This is my code

```
var eres = {
    "twentyday": 2176.8575,
    "tenday": 2235.3,
    "thirtyday": 2105.25,
    "last_close": 2168.25
}

var html = '';
var classtoadd = 'redclass'

var day10 = parseFloat(eres.tenday);
var day20 = parseFloat(eres.twentyday);
var day30 = parseFloat(eres.thirtyday);
var last_close = parseFloat(eres.last_close);

day10 = day10.toFixed(2);
day20 = day20.toFixed(2);
day30 = day30.toFixed(2);


if (day10 > last_close) {
    classtoadd = 'greenclass';
}


if (day20 > last_close) {
    classtoadd = 'greenclass';
}

if (day30 > last_close) {
    classtoadd = 'greenclass';
}

html += '<tr><td>Market Price</td><td class="">' + last_close + "</td></tr>", html += '<tr><td>10DAY</td><td class="' + classtoadd + '">' + day10 + "</td></tr>", html += '<tr><td>20 Day</td><td class="' + classtoadd + '">' + day20 + "</td></tr>", html += '<tr><td>30 Day</td><td class="' + classtoadd + '">' + day30 + "</td></tr>", html += "</tbody>"

$("#smatable").html(html)
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3336/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue

Comment: UM, you are using the same variable for 3 different states.... If the classes need to be different, you need a variable for each state. Also your use of a comma operator is strange.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you are trying to display 3 different states in one variable. You need to use a variable for each state if the states need to be different.

```
var class10 = day10 > last_close ? "greenclass" : "redclass";
var class20 = day20 > last_close ? "greenclass" : "redclass";
var class30 = day30 > last_close ? "greenclass" : "redclass";

html += '<tr><td>10 Day</td><td class="' + class10 + '">' + day10 + '</td </tr>'; 
html += '<tr><td>20 Day</td><td class="' + class20 + '">' + day20 + '</td </tr>'; 
html += '<tr><td>30 Day</td><td class="' + class20 + '">' + day30 + '</td </tr>';
```